# WL.device.getID(option) in IBM MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

**I just need to be sure about some things regarding the API**

```
WL.device.getID(option)
```

**Questions :**

1. Will this be unique to every device ?
2. Wont this id change regardless of MobileFirstAPP version releases or re-intallation of the app or product update meaning Worklight 6.0,6.2,6.3 in future too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes it will be unique to every device
2. In Worklight latest versions at least (6.2, 6.3 and above) there is no change in the WL.device.getID() between versions.

Comment: My question is will the generated ID be same for a particular device regardless of all the issues ?

Comment: Sorry, which 'issues' do you mean?

Comment: @AndrewFerrier Like Android or IOS version updates or my app Being upgraded to another version?